# Windows Forms, accessing picturebox from class in main form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, 2d

I'm making a game where I want to make things fall down and the player should try to catch it.

Currently, my items which are falling are drawn and made in a class separated from the main form, so when I try to access them from the main form where I control the gravitation.I can't seem to find the picturebox (picCoin).

Could you please take a look at my code and come with some solution?

**This is the class were i create Coins**

```
class Coin
{

    private PictureBox picCoin = new PictureBox();
    public Coin()
    {
        picCoin.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        picCoin.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\sebfre1104\source\repos\SPEL\SPEL\Resources\hamburger.png";
        picCoin.Width = 100;
        picCoin.Height = 100;
        picCoin.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;     
    }
    public void DrawTo(Form f)
    {
        f.Controls.Add(picCoin);
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds()
    {
        return picCoin.Bounds;   
    }
    public void setposition(int x, int y)
    {        
        picCoin.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }

}
```

i want to reach this picCoin in my main form so i can add gravity in private void TimerGravitation_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    bool IsJumping = false;
    List<Coin> clist = new List<Coin>();
    int poäng = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TimerGravitation_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if(!picSpelare.Bounds.IntersectsWith(picMark.Bounds) && IsJumping==false)
        {
            picSpelare.Top += 10;
        }
    }
```

I would be very grateful with any tips as this is my final project in class.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if i understanded question correctly but make picCoin public

make

```
private PictureBox picCoin = new PictureBox();
```

to

```
 public PictureBox picCoin = new PictureBox();
```

Comment: I just tried but i still can't access it in my main form, it doesn't recognise picCoin Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'picCoin' does not exist in the current context SPEL C:\Users\sebfre1104\source\repos\SPEL\SPEL\Form1.cs 28 Active

Comment: Coin test = new Coin(); do this and call it from test.picCoin

Comment: Sorry for not understanding, but should I add this in my main form or in class coin?

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should follow [Umut Arpat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60754365/7152189) (turn **picCoin** from private to public).

Then you should initialize the **Coin** class in **Form1** constructor like this:

```
private Coin _coin;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _coin = new Coin();
}
```

And then you should add picture box from **Coin** class to list of **Form1** controls like this:

```
this.Controls.Add(_coin.picCoin)
```

You can do that in **Form1** constructor too.
Don't add PictureBox to Controls of the form from the Coin class (method **DrawTo()**).

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I'm not really that great at understanding as this is my first month of programing so can you please try do develop "And then you should add picture box from Coin class to list of Form1 controls like this:

this.Controls.Add(_coin.picCoin)
You can do that in Form1 constructor too. Don't add PictureBox to Controls of the form from the Coin class (method DrawTo())."

Comment: Basically it means that this is how your **Form1** class constructor should look like: `private Coin _coin;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _coin = new Coin(); this.Controls.Add(_coin.picCoin);
}`

Comment: i did this now:  private Coin _coin = new Coin();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _coin = new Coin();
            this.Controls.Add(_coin.picCoin);
        }
is this right? cant seem to understand were to put this.Controls.Add(_coin.picCoin);

Comment: Yes, this is right. Also, you don't need to initialize Coin class twice as you did it here. You can use one of those types of initialization: 1) `private Coin _coin = new Coin();` and `_coin = new Coin();` in constructor or 2) initialization from constructor: `private Coin _coin; public Form1() { _coin = new Coin(); }`

Comment: It seems that your question has been solved. You can click '✔' to mark the appropriate reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Coin
{
    private PictureBox picCoin = new PictureBox();
    public PictureBox Box {
        get { return picCoin};
        set { picCoin = value};
    }
    ....
}
```

To use/access the box:

```
clist[i].Box // This is what you want
```